# Blow up and Higher Direct Image

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, pushforward

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth projective varieties and $Y \subset X$. Let $\pi : \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ be the blowing up of $X$ along $Y$ with exceptional divisor $E$. Here ([Direct Image by a Blow up](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418481)) it was shown that $$\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-nE) = I_{Y/X}^{n}$$ for $n \geq 1$.

From short exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-E) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{E} \longrightarrow 0$$ we get a long exact sequence

\begin{align*}
0 & \longrightarrow  \pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-E) \longrightarrow \pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}} \longrightarrow \pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{E}
\longrightarrow  \\
 & \longrightarrow R^{1}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-E)  \longrightarrow R^{1}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}} \longrightarrow R^{1}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{E} \longrightarrow  \\
& \longrightarrow  R^{2}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-E)  \longrightarrow R^{2}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}} \longrightarrow R^{2}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{E} \longrightarrow \cdots \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}

By this answer ( [Direct image of structure sheaf under blow-up along non-singular subvariety](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309401)) we have $$R^{i}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}} = 0 \tag{$**$}$$ for all $i > 0$.

Also we have

1) $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}} = \mathcal{O}_{X}$,

2) $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{E} = \mathcal{O}_{Y}$

Thus for items (1) and (2) above, we have that $\mathcal{O}_{X} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y}$ is surjective and, therefore $R^{1}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-E) = 0$.

Now, using $(**)$ in $(*)$ we get the following isomorphism $$R^{1}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{E} \longrightarrow R^{2}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-E)$$

**Question** What would it be $R^{j}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{E}$? with $j \geq 1$. It's true that $R^{i}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-E) = 0$ for $i \geq 2?$ If so, it is also true that $R^{i}\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(-nE) = 0$ for $i > 0$ and $n \geq 1$?

All help is very welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Please make the title of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/). 2. Can you do the case of a point in $\Bbb P^n$?

Comment: Can you do the case of a point in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$? @KReiser. if the center of the blow up  is a subvariety $Y$ with $\text{dim}(Y) > 0$, is the procedure the same?

Comment: @ZlattanR.S . As $E^{2} = -1$, we have $\mathcal{O}_{E}(E)$  has non-zero global sections. Thus, $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(E) \simeq \pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}$.

Comment: In the case mentioned by you above, I am trying to resolve it, without success, for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $i:Y\to X$ and $\widetilde{i}:E\to \widetilde{X}$ be the closed immersions. First, we note that $i_*R^i(\pi|_E)_*\mathcal{O}_E = R^i(\pi_*\widetilde{i}_*\mathcal{O}_E)$ by looking at the definition of $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{F}$ as the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U\mapsto H^i(U,\mathcal{F}(U))$. So it's enough to compute the higher direct images along the map $\pi|_E: E\to Y$.

If $Y\subset X$ is smooth, then the restriction $\pi|_E: E\to Y$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb P(\mathcal{N}_{Y/X})\to Y$, the projectivization of the normal bundle $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$, a locally free sheaf of rank $\dim X-\dim Y$. We may find an affine cover $\{\operatorname{Spec} A_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $Y$ which trivializes $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$, so that on this cover we are in the situation of $\phi:\Bbb P^n_{A_i}\to \operatorname{Spec} A_i$. By the well-known calculation of the cohomology of line bundles on projective space, we see that all higher direct images $R^i\phi_*\mathcal{O}(d)=0$ for $i\neq 0,n$ and $d > -n-1$ in the case $i=n$.

This shows that all higher direct images of $\mathcal{O}_E$ vanish, answering the first question. Combining this with $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}=0$ for all $i>0$, we see that $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}(-E)=0$ for all $i>0$.

To get the result for $R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}(-nE)$ with $n>1$, twist the exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}(-E) \to \mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X} \to \mathcal{O}_E \to 0$ by $-E$, note that $\mathcal{O}_E(-nE)=\mathcal{O}_E(n)$, and then by induction we see the result for all $n>0$.

Comment: Hi, KReiser. First, thanks for the answer. Second, I just didn't understand the following isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{E}(-nE) = \mathcal{O}_{E}(n)$. Again, Thank you.

Comment: This is a standard feature of a blowup which should be covered in every text which deals with the construction. Briefly, one can see that the negative of the line bundle associated to the divisor $E$ is locally determined by equations which are homogeneous of degree one in the blowup variables, which gives $\mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}(-E)\cong \mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}(1)$, and after restricting to $E$ and taking tensor powers, we get the requested identification. (This is also mentioned briefly in some of the linked posts - it may be wise to include such issues in your question in the future.)

Comment: Ok, KReiser. Thank you very much for your support.